# Why does amsmath print a warning about a foreign command?

Tags: packages, amsmath, warnings

I was wondering what was the cause of the following warning message with the specific `\usepackage` used below:

Using the following:

#### Preamble

```
\documentclass[amssymb,twocolumn,aps]{revtex4}
 \usepackage{times,amsmath,latexsym}
```

#### Warning message

```
Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atopwithdelims;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 56.
```

**Line 56**

`\[ \frac{gcd(m,n)}{n} {n\choose m} \] 
         is an integer for all pairs of integers $n\geq m\geq 1$.`

Comment: What is on line 56 of your file?

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: It's classified top secret info, I wouldn't be able to disclose that with you, I am sorry. Just joking, it was cool pretending to be a agent there for a bit. It is here below:

`\[ \frac{gcd(m,n)}{n} {n\choose m} \]
is an integer for all pairs of integers $n\geq m\geq 1$.`

Comment: Aha.  Replacing `n \choose m` with `\binom{n}{m}` will make the warning go away.

Comment: @Matt: Thank You, that sure did take care of it flawlessly.

Comment: See also: [fractions - What is the difference between \over and \frac? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73822/what-is-the-difference-between-over-and-frac/) && [best practices - Practical consequences of using \over vs. \frac? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365328/practical-consequences-of-using-over-vs-frac)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

`\atopwithdelims` is a TeX math primitive command. If you use `amsmath`, you don't need `\atopwithdelims` or `\atop`, use `amsmath` macros such as `\frac`, `\binom`, `\genfrac` etc. instead.

If a class or package uses this command, or a command such as `\choose` which uses it, you would get this warning. I would ignore the warning then, otherwise I would have to redefine the concerned macros of the package or class.

Alternatively, I suggest that you use `\binom{a}{n}`.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what it is. Using the `\choose` command for the binomial coefficients. So you suggest ignoring the warning since I am using the `\choose` ?

Comment: @night owl: I suggest using `\binom{a}{b}` instead of `{a \choose b}`.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Given that you use `\choose` as an example, would you consider moving the use of `\binom{n}{m}` into your answer? I suspect many people find their way to this question when using `\choose`.