# List of higher-level LaTeX commands corresponding to TeX commands

Tags: macros, best-practices, big-list

Since LaTeX is a format built on top of TeX, it surely has several high level abstractions that perform similarly to TeX commands, with some added error-handling functionality, for example. I always find scattered advice saying

> Instead of `\def`, use `\newcommand`

...which I'm sure also applies to other commands.

Is there a document compiling such matches? If not, how about we compile them here? So far, I can think of the following. I may or may not be right with some of them, but I hope it illustrates my point.

```
\def --> \newcommand, \renewcommand
\hskip --> \hspace
\vskip --> \vspace
```

The objective is to avoid using low-level TeX commands unless absolutely necessary. And even if it were necessary, confine them inside macro definitions.

I imagine this to be community wiki. <s>So one matchup per answer</s>. A big-list community wiki answer has been started below, categorized according to problem domains. Feel free to edit and/or add problem domains and matchups.

A `TeX --> LaTeX` matchup means that they tackle the same problem domain, so one or more TeX commands may match one or more LaTeX commands. Also include with your answer the reasons (or a link) explaining why the LaTeX alternative is better as a high-level implementation.

Comment: I think that this is great, but I'd rather go for a single comunity wiki answer with the commands grouped in some logical fashion.  Moreover (having just dipped my toe in the murky waters of LaTeX3 syntax) I'd like to add LaTeX3-type commands to this.

Comment: @Andrew, right, that's part of what I envisioned. Maybe have everyone add in their matchup, then edit the big-list answer, with a link to their answer which contains their explanation.

Comment: While it is not the plain list you asked for, 
http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf
can provide some answers.

Answer (score 20):

On the left are TeX commands, on the right are LaTeX commands with similar functionality.

### Macro definitions

- `\def`, `\gdef` --> `\newcommand*`, `\providecommand*`, `\renewcommand*`
- `\long\def`, `\long\gdef` --> `\newcommand`, `\providecommand`, `\renewcommand`

  For commands with a scope, i.e. including grouping, LaTeX provides `\newenvironment` and `\renewenvironment`.

### Mathematics

- `$ ... $` --> `\( ... \)` with `fixltx2e`, see [Are ( and ) preferable to $](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to)
- `$$ ... $$` --> `\[ ... \]`, see [Why is [ … ] preferable to $$](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)
- `\over` --> `\frac`
- `\atop`, `\atopwithdelims`, `\choose` --> `\genfrac` and derived `amsmath` commands such as `\binom`, see [Why does amsmath print a warning about a foreign command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19587/warning-message-involving-amsmath)
- `\leqno, \eqno` --> `equation` environment, optional `leqno` class or `amsmath` option

### Tables

- `\cr`, `\crcr` --> `\\`, `\tabularnewline`

### Spacing

- `\kern`, `\hskip` --> `\hspace`
- `\vskip` --> `\vspace`

### Positioning

- `\centerline` --> `\centering` or the `center` environment
- `\raise` --> `\raisebox`

### Miscellaneous

- `\uppercase` --> `\MakeUppercase`

Comment: The high number of upvotes to the question shows that the question is interesting. So there's a CW answer now, feel free to extend it. It would be great if you supplement suggestions with links to existing questions & answers on the site.

Comment: I would add the commands `\(re)newenvironemt` and `begin{...}`...`end{...}`. And what do you think about font commands like `\bf`?

Comment: @Marco: `\bf`, `\it` are also obsolete LaTeX 2.09 commands, that's why I didn't add it at first. Just edit :-) no need to ask. I'm sure you make good additions.

Comment: I especially like the links to questions, that's a nice feature of having this list *here* rather than on some website somewhere.

Answer (score 8):

For what it is worth, the [nag package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nag) will warn you whenever you use a TeX command instead of a LaTeX one. Good way to learn which commands are <strike>deprecated</strike> *outdated and superseded* (quoting the nag documentation).

Comment: How, exactly, can the underlying language primitives be "deprecated"?!