# TeX within a LaTeX document?

Tags: macros

I'm new to LaTeX and I guess I'm still a little confused about the difference between TeX and LaTeX. Under what circumstances would you actually need to define new TeX macros within a LaTeX document? What's the difference between `\def` and `\newcommand` (other than the fact that one is TeX and the other is LaTeX)? Can someone give me an example?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/what-are-tex-and-latex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LaTeX is based on TeX, see:

- [What is the difference between TeX and LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49/what-is-the-difference-between-tex-and-latex)

You can use TeX within LaTeX documents, however it's recommended to use LaTeX if possible because

- LaTeX is a higher abstraction level
- LaTeX does more error checks
- Using LaTeX commands in LaTeX commands is simply more consistent, because TeX command don't have to know the LaTeX context they are used within, while LaTeX commands may do

Here's a helpful list regarding LaTeX commands vs. TeX commands:

- [List of higher-level LaTeX commands corresponding to TeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26742/list-of-higher-level-latex-commands-corresponding-to-tex-commands/26922#26922)

LaTeX's `\newcommand` checks if a macro name already exists, so you cannot accidentally overwrite an existing macro with the same name. However, you can still use `\def`, as said above, for example if you would like to overcome `\newcommand` syntax restrictions. See:

- [What is the difference between \def and \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/655/what-is-the-difference-between-def-and-newcommand)

There's a lot of LaTeX documentation explaining `\newcommand` and examples. However, you can find a lot of examples using this site's search feature, such as

- [searching for the tag {macro} together with the keyword `\newcommand`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmacros%5D%20newcommand)

Answer (score 5):

The difference between TeX is not analogous to the difference between, say, C and C++, where it is actually an issue to directly include C code in a C++ program.  It's more like the difference between a simple HTML text box like the one I'm using and a fancy text editor like Emacs.  (I admit that the analogy between a typesetting engine and a text editor is not that inspired.)  Sure, you can use an Emacs window as a text box, but it has a ton of features that make entering and editing text faster and easier, and an infinite capacity to extend them.  Of course, in the middle of your hyper-adept Meta-Super-whatever editing session you choose just to type a few lines, it will not break the program.  It may even be faster or easier.

Thus it is with TeX and LaTeX.  Unlike C++, LaTeX does not replace TeX, but rather, it replaces TeX *idioms*.  The language would still work the same way if you tried to use it, but you have the option (strongly encouraged) to use it differently.  In particular, `\def` and `\newcommand` both define the same kind of "command": a TeX macro.  It's just that `\newcommand` is smarter about it, while `\def` is more flexible (and thus more dangerous).

Like with Emacs versus text boxes, most of the time you are doing things that don't depend on TeX vs LaTeX at all: entering plain text is the same in both.  Also, I have lied in that it is possible for some TeX commands (even primitive commands like `\def`, or in practice, `\atop`) to be redefined to give errors in LaTeX.  Also note that I am not going to tell you what commands are actually in TeX (as compared to LaTeX) since LaTeX is designed in such a way that you shouldn't even need to know.

I should say that I have never used Emacs.