# What is the difference between \over and \frac?

Tags: fractions

What is the difference between
`{some-expression}\over{another-expression}`
and
`\frac{some-expression}{another-expression}`
?

Which is preferable?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

The command `\over` is a so-called "primitive" command that's available in Plain TeX and in LaTeX. `\frac` is a LaTeX-only command that builds on the `\over` macro to provide something that's much less likely to throw unexpected errors if the user doesn't handle the syntax of the `\over` command just right.

Assuming you have the `amsmath` package loaded, the `\frac` command is defined as follows:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\frac}[2]{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\@@over#2}}
```

where `\@@over` is an `amsmath`-internal version of `\over`. Note that the first argument of `\frac` (the numerator) is carefully encased in a `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` construct and that the entire command's "content" is surrounded by a double set of curly braces. The braces serve to remove potential ambiguities that might arise from a less than fully careful use of the `\over` command by itself.

If you're a user of LaTeX, there's no reason whatsoever for not using the `\frac` command -- *and* several good reasons for not using the `\over` command directly. In short, if you use LaTeX, use `\frac`.

Comment: I would go as far as to say that including `\over` (and friends `\atop` etc.) were a bad design decision by Knuth. 

TeX uses different layout style for display mode, text mode, superscripts, and subscript. However, because of macros like `\over`, when TeX is building the math token list, the current math mode is not known. This causes all sorts of difficulties like having to use `\mathchoice` in simple macros like `\text`. If macros like `\over` are ruled out, the design of a lot of macros will simplify a lot.

Comment: Could you give an example of the sort of problems that could occur with `\over`?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - Did you see the example given in egreg's answer?

Comment: I've discussed this with Knuth.  His rationale for using `\over` rather than `\frac` is that it's the natural vocabulary of a *mathematician*, and his model for TeX was that of a mathematician, not a computer scientist.  (One concludes that there are concepts which are for him more important than ease of programming.)

Answer (score 42):

The latter is preferable. It corrects a behavior that in some situations can reveal itself in a bad way. The LaTeX definition is

```
\def\frac#1#2{{\begingroup #1\endgroup\over #2}}
```

In some cases an assignment made in the numerator can affect also the denominator. It's difficult to produce it with standard LaTeX commands, but you can compare the result of

```
\[
\fam0 a\over b
\]
```

with

```
\[
\frac{\fam0 a}{b}
\]
```

In the first case both "a" and "b" will be upright, which is probably not expected.

Another relevant argument against the `\over` syntax is that it's foreign to LaTeX, which always uses first the command and then its argument and never an "infix" syntax. Moreover the grouping around `numerator\over denominator` is automatically provided, avoiding mistakes such as

```
1\over 2 \over 3
```

### Update

Starting from the 2019-10-01 release of LaTeX, the definition of `\frac` uses `\DeclareRobustCommand`, as part of a program to remove as many fragile commands as possible:

```latex
% latex.ltx, line 4705:
\DeclareRobustCommand\frac[2]{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\over#2}}
```

In olden times it was not possible to make all commands robust, because of memory restrictions. These considerations are no longer a problem.

The `amsmath` package has used `\DeclareRobustCommand` for its modified definition of `\frac` for many years.

Comment: *never an "infix" syntax*
… except for with `\choose` …

Comment: @MikaelVejdemo-Johansson `\choose` is not documented in the LaTeX manual, as far as I know. :)

Answer (score 21):

In *[User’s Guide for the amsmath Package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)* p.14 it is written the following:

> The primitive generalized fraction commands `\over`,
> `\overwithdelims`, `\atop`, `\atopwithdelims`, `\above`,
> `\abovewithdelims` produce warning messages if used with the amsmath
> package, for reasons discussed in [technote.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/technote.tex).

And in [*Technical notes on the amsmath package*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amsmath/technote.pdf) p.2:

> Not only is the unusual syntax of the TeX primitives rather out of
> place in LaTeX, but furthermore *that syntax seems to be responsible
> for one of the most significant flaws in TeX's mathematical
> typesetting capabilities*: the fact that the current mathstyle at any
> given point in a math formula cannot be determined until the end of
> the formula, because of the possibility that a following generalized
> fraction command will change the mathstyle of the preceding material.

> (...)

> *There are additional bad consequences following from the syntax
> of those generalized fraction commands that only become evident when
> you do some writing of nontrivial macros for math use.* For example, as
> things currently stand you cannot measure the size of any object in
> math without going through `\mathchoice` and leaving and reentering math
> mode via `\hbox{$` (which then introduces complications regarding
> `\everymath` and `\mathsurround`). And it seems that uncertainty about the
> current mathstyle is the only barrier to allowing the use of mu units
> with `\vrule`, to make vertical struts in constructing compound symbols
> or notation. And so on and so forth.

Comment: The hyperlinks you provided don't appear to work anymore. Can you provide updates?

Comment: Links ave been repaired.

Comment: To be fair, you avoiding \over will probably *not* make TeX change to fix that oddity because of the stability requirement. (by the way [LuaTeX has `\Ustack`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1223/is-there-a-test-for-the-different-styles-inside-maths-mode) to fix that issue already)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, I found [\over doesn't need curly braces whereas \frac does](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

```
\[ P(n,m) = {n! \over (n-m)!} \] <!-- { } for {n! \over (n-m!)} -->
\[ n! \over (n-m)! \]
\[ P(n,m) = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!} \] <!-- { } for \frac {} {} -->
\[ \frac{n!}{(n-m)!} \]
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add an screenshot of your result and explain the difference.