# fractional: differences between \frac{}{} and { \over }

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between \over and \frac?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73822/what-is-the-difference-between-over-and-frac)

I just learned that `{3 \over 4}` and `\frac{3}{4}` can produce the same fractional 3/4. So I wonder what differences are between them?

Comment: I guess that `\over` is obsolete command and should not be used.