# \atop vs. \substack for multiple lines under a sum

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I did a search trying to find out how one can typeset multiple lines under a sum and found out that there is the possibility to use `\atop` or `\substack` together with a remark that one shouldn't use `\atop`.

Is there any good reason for that? Does it commit some typographical sins I am not aware of?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1988473/2541573

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73825/5001 for a discussion why `\over` (which shares many similarities with `\atop`) shouldn't be used in LaTeX documents -- any why `\frac` should be used instead. The syntax of the TeX "primitive" commands `\atop` and `\over` is quite different from that used by most other TeX macros, and if you violate one of these syntax rules you're liable to get weird, bad crashes. In contrast, `\substack` is crafted much more robustly.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Using `\atop` is abusing its functionality; if you want to turn a screw, sometimes a knife can help, but a screwdriver is surely better.

In other words, use `\substack` that has been specifically defined for this task and can accommodate any number of lines. It's also easier to use even for two lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{1\le i\le n\atop i\ne j}\quad
\sum_{\scriptstyle 1\le i\le n\atop\scriptstyle i\ne j}\quad
\sum_{\substack{1\le i\le n\\ i\ne j}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The first is wrong; the second is complicated to write. With `\substack` you also avoid the warning

```
Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atop;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 6.
```

Comment: Why is it wrong to have a smaller font size? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @fifaltra The font size should be the same as if there is a single line.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the clarification :)