# How to write two subscripts on top of each other in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I want to write something like

```
Q_{a\in A,b\in B}
```

but with $b\in B$ being below $a \in A$. What is the way to do so?

Comment: P.S. I don't know why but math mode seems not to be working this is why you see the dollars in my question.

Comment: What about using `$Q_{a\in A}^{b\in B}$`?

Comment: On why math doesn't display here see [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1272).

Comment: Also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153490/atop-vs-substack-for-multiple-lines-under-a-sum

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `\substack`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[ Q_{\substack{a\in A\\b\in B}} \]%

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use the `\genfrac` command from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
Q_{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{a\in A}{b\in B}} 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `align` enviroment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
$Q_{\begin{aligned}
\scriptscriptstyle a & \scriptscriptstyle\in A\\[-1em]
\scriptscriptstyle b  & \scriptscriptstyle\in B
\end{aligned}}$
\end{document}
```

[image]