# how to represent Sum in latex

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to represent the following sum in LaTeX.

[image]

I have tried it in the following way:

```
$$\sum_{{1 \le k \le n}_{ k odd}} k^2$$
```

But I have not got the desired result. Please help me.

Comment: duplicate: [\atop vs. \substack for multiple lines under a sum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153490/579).  also, instead of `$$`, use `\[ ... \]`.  (and for good measure, read the `amsmath` users guide {`texdoc amsldoc`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to load the `amsmath` package and employ its `\substack` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newpxtext}             % Palatino text font
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm} % Euler math font

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{\substack{1 \le k < 100 \\ \textup{$k$ odd}}} k^2
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Thanks for this. I changed `\text` to `\textup`. (We don't know if the default text font is sans-serif -- in which case "odd" would look, well, odd, if it were typed in the roman font face...)

Comment: What is `\usepackage[euler-digits]`?

Comment: @Sebastiano - `euler-digits` is an option passed to the package [eulervm](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/eulervm). I included the font-related directives in order to replicate the "look" of the OP's screenshot.