# how to force text to write in two or more lines in overset command

Tags: overset

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
 \overset{-1*R_{4}\rightarrow R_{3} \\ -2*R_{4}\rightarrow R_{2} }{\rightarrow}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

I get everything in one line over the arrow, but i need it to be in two lines as indicated by the line break `\\`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Try checking out the `substack` command [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153490/atop-vs-substack-for-multiple-lines-under-a-sum).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `subarray` environment. To make the arrow as long as the text you can use `\xrightarrow`.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    With \verb|\rightarrow|:

    \[
        \overset{
            \begin{subarray}{l}
                -1*R_{4}\rightarrow R_{3}\\
                -2*R_{4}\rightarrow R_{2}
            \end{subarray}
        }{\rightarrow}
    \]

    With \verb|\xrightarrow|:

    \[
        \xrightarrow{
            \begin{subarray}{l}
                -1*R_{4}\rightarrow R_{3}\\
                -2*R_{4}\rightarrow R_{2}
            \end{subarray}
        }
    \]

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you might have noticed from the answer above, spacing above the `\rightarrow` is an issue. My answer uses the `substack` command to achieve your stated aim of multiple lines, and a new macro found [here](https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=3cz1) for changing the space with `overset`.

Output:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\oset}[3][0ex]{%
    \mathrel{\mathop{#3}\limits^{
            \vbox to#1{\kern-2\ex@
                \hbox{$\scriptstyle#2$}\vss}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{gather*}
     \oset[3ex]{\substack{-1*R_{4}\rightarrow R_{3} \\ -2*R_{4}\rightarrow R_{2} }}{\rightarrow}
    \end{gather*}

\end{document}
```