# How to write Gaussian reduction?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, gauss

I am still a newbie in LaTeX and I am trying to write something like that but I couldn't find how to do so.

[image]

Is there an efficient way to write this and if I have multiple steps to show in the reduction how do I align them?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please do tell us what you've tried so far and where you feel you're getting stuck.

Comment: Minor nit: I’m more used to seeing columns of numbers align right than left or center. Sebastiano’s answer already matches the output you want, so +1.

Answer (score 8):

I would use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(
  \begin{array}{*4{l}|l}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & b_1\\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & b_2-b_1\\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & b_3-b_1\\
    0 & 4 & 4 & 5 & b_4-b_1\\
  \end{array}
  \right)
  \xrightarrow[L_4 \rightarrow L_4-2L_2]{L_3 \rightarrow L_3-L_2}
  \left(
  \begin{array}{*4{l}|l}
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & b_1\\
    0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & b_2-b_1\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b_3-b_1-b_2\\
    0 & 0 & -2 & -1 & b_4+b_1-2b_2\\
  \end{array}
  \right).
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you're using `array`, you might consider aligning the first four columns as `4r` instead of `4l` so that the minus signs don't shove the negative values out of line.

Comment: Thanks! However, I have another question. I am trying to write this \[\left(\begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \frac{1}{4} \\ -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\right)\] but is there a way to align number with \begin{pmatrix} and the fractions are a little too close of each others (I don't know how to space them)

Comment: @barbarabeeton this is what I would have done for myself, but I wanted to reproduce what Moh18 wanted.

Comment: @Moh18 I suggest opening another subject to address this new problem :-)

Comment: @FranckPastor https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512111/aligning-and-spaces-for-negative-numbers-and-fractions-in-a-matrix

Comment: @FranckPastor If, between the two matrices, I have to show more that two steps. For example, $L_4 \rightarrow L_4-2L_2$ ,$L_3 \rightarrow L_3-L_2$,$L_2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$. How can I write them under or over the $\xrightarrow$?

Comment: @barbarabeeton If, between the two matrices, I have to show more that two steps. For example, $L_4 \rightarrow L_4-2L_2$ ,$L_3 \rightarrow L_3-L_2$,$L_2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$. How can I write them under or over the $\xrightarrow$?

Comment: @Moh18 -- For expressions over/under `xrightarrow`, look at the instructions and examples in section 4.9, "Extensible arrows", in the `amsmath` user guide (`texdoc amsldoc`).  Also, the answers here do show the proper input method.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT: 2020-7-18** Another option could be using the [`nicematrix`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf) package (see the recent version and the comment of the author of the package). Here there is my approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\left(\begin{NiceArray}{cccc|l}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & b_1\\
0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & b_2-b_1\\
0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & b_3-b_1\\
0 & 4 & 4 & 5 & b_4-b_1
\end{NiceArray}\right)
\xrightarrow[L_4 \rightarrow L_4-2L_2]{L_3 \rightarrow L_3-L_2}
\left(\begin{NiceArray}{cccc|l}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & b_1\\
0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & b_2-b_1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b_3-b_1-b_2\\
0 & 0 & -2 & -1 & b_4+b_1-2b_2\\
\end{NiceArray}\right).\]
\end{document}
```

### ADDENDUM by comment of the user

There are several procedures to have, for example, on the same arrow your reductions: see this link [how to force text to write in two or more lines in overset command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/454087/how-to-force-text-to-write-in-two-or-more-lines-in-overset-command?noredirect=1&lq=1)
for example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\left(\begin{NiceArray}{cccc|l}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & b_1\\
0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & b_2-b_1\\
0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & b_3-b_1\\
0 & 4 & 4 & 5 & b_4-b_1
\end{NiceArray}\right)
\xrightarrow{
            \begin{subarray}{l}
                L_4 \rightarrow L_4-2L_2\\
                L_3 \rightarrow L_3-L_2\\
                L_2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}
                %%% here you can add other steps
            \end{subarray}
        }
\left(\begin{NiceArray}{cccc|l}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & b_1\\
0 & 2 & 3 & 3 & b_2-b_1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b_3-b_1-b_2\\
0 & 0 & -2 & -1 & b_4+b_1-2b_2\\
\end{NiceArray}\right).\]
\end{document}
```

You, if it is possible, read the guide of `nicematrix` package you could get a better result (see the image of the guide to pag. 18, for example).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you response!

Comment: @Moh18 I'm happy when I help someone. Glad I helped you.

Comment: If, between the two matrices, I have to show more that two steps. For example, $L_4 \rightarrow L_4-2L_2$ ,$L_3 \rightarrow L_3-L_2$,$L_2 \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$. How can I write them under or over the $\xrightarrow$?

Comment: @Moh18 Hi, I have done an addendum for your request. My best regards,

Comment: In this answer, since version 5.0 of `nicematrix` one must write `cccc|l` instead of `CCCC|L` in the preambles of `{NiceArray}` (but there is an option for backward compatibility).

Comment: @F.Pantigny I'll correct that immediately and thank you immensely.