# Aligning and spaces for negative numbers and fractions in a matrix

Tags: matrices, mathtools, gauss

As the title says, when I am writing my code the fractions are a little too close to eah others.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 \\ 
    -\frac{1}{3} \\ 
     \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \\ 
     2
  \end{pmatrix}
  \right).
\]
\end{document}
```

EDIT : I don't why it  doesn't show the matrix here.

Comment: You could add e.g. `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` before `\begin{pmatrix}`. Your code does not compile because `\frac{2}` misses a denominator.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat oops I have miswritten, it was \sqrt instead of \frac

Comment: You also shouldn't encase a `pmatrix` environment in `\left(` ... `\right)`.

Comment: @Mico Normally, I have multiple vectors  into this

Comment: The reason the output of your example doesn't show up here is explained in [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1272/579)

Answer (score 2):

You can add some additional vertical spacing manually, like this (approximately):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 \\ 
    -\frac{1}{3} \\[.5ex] 
     \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \\
     2
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Short of increasing the value of `\arraystretch` by a factor of two or more, here are two solutions to the problem of the denominator term of the upper fraction being too close to the numerator term of the lower fraction:

- For a modest increase in vertical separation, insert a `\mathstrut` directive in the numerator of the lower fraction.
- For a more pronounced increase in vertical separation, insert a `\mathstrut` directive in the denominator of the upper fraction.

Incidentally, the definition of `\mathstrut` is `\vphantom{(}`, i.e., it's a typographic strut that has the height and depth of the `(` symbol.

The following screenshot shows first the original setup, then the first solution, then the second solution.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -\frac{1}{3} \\ 
     \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} 
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -\frac{1}{3} \\ 
     \frac{1\mathstrut}{2\sqrt{2}} 
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    -\frac{1}{3\mathstrut} \\ 
     \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} 
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```