# Writing limits with additional conditions

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

I gave a quick search, but didn't find something similarly, atleast for limits.

I am trying to write something like:

```
 $\lim_{\binom{x\to 0}{x>0}} f(x)$
```

My intention is to put the limit with the two conditions under it. For now I came up with the idea to use the `\binom`, but that has some braces near it. I would appreciate a better idea.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Something like `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\lim_{\substack{x\to 0\\ x>0}} f(x)$ or
$\lim\limits_{\substack{x\to 0\\ x>0}} f(x)$
\end{document}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an alternative for your question using the option `smallmatrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[\lim_{\begin{smallmatrix} x \to 0 & \\ x>0 \end{smallmatrix}} f(x)\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zacky You're absolutely right. I knew it right away, then, but I'm slow as a snail.

Comment: @Zacky Excuse me for my bad English. I not use often Mathjax but with LaTeX the  `\tag{1}` into an ambient in math-mode you have (1) at the end of the line correctly. Use for example `\usepackage{amsmath}` package.

Comment: Sebastiano's solution has not the text under "lim" centered, and more space between "lim" and "f(x)" than Marmot solution under the OP question. `\substack` is specifically designed for the task asked, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153502/132405).

Comment: @quark67 yes of course. I know the link that you have added :-). But I want, only, create a creative alternative code (not the usual). For my humble opinion the difference is more little. In addition I have upvoted the comment of great user marmot.