# How do I write more than 1 condition under a \bigwedge?

Tags: syntax

What I want:

[image]

Now I can easily write the first condition `$w \in V(G)$` myself, but how can I add a second (and a 3rd and a 4th) condition under it?

Comment: Try `\substack` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7503/125871) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153490/125871)

Comment: @SandyG worked beautifully, thank you!