# How to get double subscripts underneath entire symbol

Tags: formatting, subscripts

I'm trying to get double subscripts in the following manner:

[image]

Currently, the closest thing I have to this is `\displaystyle\bigwedge_{{r < s}_{r \in Q}}` but this will obviously put the subscript under the *s* instead of underneath the entire `\bigwedge`. Is there a package and command I need to include in order to do this?

Comment: `\bigwedge_{\substack{ line1 \\ line2 }}` requires `amsmath` which everyone is expected to be using.

Comment: Or [syntax - How do I write more than 1 condition under a \bigwedge? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574021/how-do-i-write-more-than-1-condition-under-a-bigwedge?noredirect=1&lq=1) for an exact match, but it's closed as duplicate of the former one anyway