Formatting qualifications for a summation variable
I'm attempting to write a summation over a variable such that it follows a few qualifications. Here is my current attempt, but the formatting looks very odd. If anyone could help me to improve it, that would be really appreciated.
(This is not my actual function, just a simplified version for the sake of focusing on the question.)
So in this case, the sum will add together h(a) for all a where a \leq n and |a| = b.

$$
f(n ,b) = \sum_
{a : \left\{
     \begin{aligned}
       a \leq n \\ |a| = b
     \end{aligned}
  \right\} 
} 
h(a)
$$


See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153490/18228

Or $a \in S$ where `$S = {...}$,

With \substack:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
f(n ,b) = \sum_{
  a: \left\{
     \substack{a \leq n \\ |a| = b}
  \right\}
}
h(a)
\]

\end{document}

Never use $$ in a LaTeX document environment, see Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?


In addition to using \substack (a macro provided by the amsmath package) instead of an aligned environment, I would recommend simplifying and streamlining the material below the \sum symbol.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class 
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for '\substack' macro

\begin{document}
\[
f(n,b) = \sum_{\substack{ a\leq n \\ |a|=b }} h(a)
\]
\end{document}

