# How do I make fractions automatically displayed in lines properly?

Tags: math-mode, fractions

I would like to know how to make code of fractions in [`article`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/article) class more easy to handle.

Usually, if I type `${a \over b}$` then LaTeX does not display `$a/b$`, which is what I want. So I have to say `$a/b$` and `$${a \over b}$$` separately, which is to me annoying.

Is there something I can do so that whenever I type `${a \over b}$` in `article` class then LaTeX knows to automatically display `$a/b$`?

Comment: So you want `${a \over b}$` to *always* be `${a/b}$`? Without exclusion? Note that you should really use `$\frac{a}{b}$ and not `\over`...

Comment: @Werner: Yeah, for now I want no exclusion. Thank you so much.

Comment: Have a look at `\sfrac{1}{2}` from the `xfrac` package

Comment: don't use `\over` in latex!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Pardon me, may I know why? What are the possible consequences?

Comment: `\over` is not a latex command and its syntax is completely different to all latex commands, that is why latex defines \frac. Its syntax makes it very hard to customise the behaviour, for example if a document is marked up using `\frac` `\frac` could easily be redefined as in the answers here to use different styles. If a document is marked up with `\over` then changing the style means editing the document. Also the `amsmath` package makes `\over` make a warning to strongly discourage its use.

Comment: @Chou - The LaTeX macro `\frac` is a carefully designed "wrapper" around the "primitive" TeX directive `\over`. See the posting [What is the difference between \over and \frac?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73822/5001) for more information on this subject, incl. why there's no good reason for using `\over` directly in a LaTeX document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

I've defined a `\myfrac` command that outputs `a/b` when in inline math, `\frac{a}{b}` for display mode.

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myfrac}[2]{%
    \ifinner#1/#2%
    \else\frac{#1}{#2}%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

this is inline mode $\myfrac{a}{b}$

\bigskip

and this is display mode

\[\myfrac{a}{b}\]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

This has,however, the drawback of printing `a/b` for `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle`, too.

If you don't like this behavior, define `\myfrac` as

```
\newcommand{\myfrac}[2]{%
  \mathchoice%
  {\frac{#1}{#2}}% \displaystyle
  {#1/#2}%         \textstyle
  {\frac{#1}{#2}}% \scriptstyle
  {\frac{#1}{#2}}% \scriptscriptstyle
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myfrac}[2]{%
  \mathchoice%
  {\frac{#1}{#2}}% \displaystyle
  {#1/#2}%         \textstyle
  {\frac{#1}{#2}}% \scriptstyle
  {\frac{#1}{#2}}% \scriptscriptstyle
}

\begin{document}

this is inline mode $\myfrac{a}{b}$

\bigskip

and this is display mode

\[\myfrac{a}{b}c^{\myfrac{d}{e}}\]

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]