# Change the behavior of subscript \frac in inline math

Tags: math-mode, fractions, inline

I am writing a document which contains a lot of half-integer indices.

In display mode, `x_{i + \frac {1} {2}}` looks fine.

However, in inline mode, having several `x_{i + \frac {1} {2}}` messes up the interline spacing. `x_{i + 1/2}` looks fine, though.

I would like a command that allows switching between both:
- `x_{i + \frac {1} {2}}` when in display mode,
- `x_{i + 1/2}` when in inline mode.

I tried playing around with the answer from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223557/how-do-i-make-fractions-automatically-displayed-in-lines-properly), but could not get it to work properly in my case. Any ideas?

Comment: You may be able to do it by hooking into `\everymath{..}` and activating a bool, for instance. Or making `_` active and hooking a bool in there.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just type `x_{i + 1/2}` when you are in inline math?  First, these are fewer letters to type than `x_{i + \frac{1}{2}}` and second there is no autodetection for inline math mode, which means you will very soon hit corner cases.

Comment: @HenriMenke: This is of course possible. For the moment, I am using a command `\iph` to represent `i + \frac {1} {2}`. My question probably was not clear enough: I would like to replace the `\frac` in the previous expression by a command that automatically chooses which fraction expression to display. However, since there is no autodetection for inline math mode, it would be hard to get such a behavior...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution, altough in LaTeX2e there's no real machinery around `\everymath` so you are using the primitive and it may interfere with other packages (I don't really know any example, but it's possible that there's).

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\newif\ifinlinemath
\newcommand*\versatilefrac[3][]{\ifinlinemath{#2#1/#3}\else\frac{#2}{#3}\fi}
\everymath{\inlinemathtrue\everymath{}}

\begin{document}

$x_{i + \versatilefrac{1}{2}}$
\[
  x_{i + \versatilefrac{1}{2}}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd use `\mathchoice`.  Of course, then also fractions inside fractions in displaystyle would be converted to the slashed form.

Comment: @Manuel: That seems to work, without conflicts so far! Thanks! However, it does not work in `align` environments. Is there a way to modify your command to work in such environments?

Comment: @HenriMenke But how does `\mathchoice` now if it's a subscript in inline or display math?