# \newline command is not working inside a displayed equation

Tags: math-mode, errors, line-breaking

```
\begin{frame}

$$\partial_t \bar{A_{ij}}= e^{-4\phi}(-(D_iD_j\alpha)^{TF}+\alpha(R_{ij}^{TF}-8\pi S_{ij}^{TF})+\alpha(K\bar{A_{ij}}-2\bar{A_{il}}\bar{A_j^l})
+\beta^k\partial_k\bar{A_{ij}} + \newline
\bar{A_{ik}}\partial_j \beta^k+\bar{A_{kj}}\partial_i \beta^k-{2 \over 3}\bar{A_{ij}}\partial_k \beta^k)$$
\end{frame}
```

I am trying `\newline` to split the equation into the second line but it is not working.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please always add a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to your questions instead of only a code snippet. With the code snippet we can only assume that you are using `beamer`. With a MWE we would know the class and the needed math packages. And we could reproduce the problem and test our suggestions.

Comment: Please also read: "[What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/what-are-the-differences-between-align-equation-and-displaymath)" and "[Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)"

Answer (score 3):

I assume your document uses the `beamer` document class. If so, the formula suffers from several problems.

- First and foremost, `$$ ...$$` is designed for single-line displayed equations: One cannot have line breaks in such a construct. I suggest you use a `multline*` environment.
- The formula has multiple instances of things like `\bar{A_{ij}}`. The `\bar` "accent" isn't long enough to span the entire formula. Write either `\bar{A}_{ij}` or, if the bar accent is supposed to span the entire subformula, `\overline{A_{ij}}`. In the code below, I've chosen the former option.
- Your formula contains the subformula `{2 \over 3}`. One should not use the Plain-TeX `\over` directive in a LaTeX document. You should write either `\frac{2}{3}` or -- if you want a smaller term, with text-style fraction term appearance -- `\tfrac{2}{3}`. See the posting [What is the difference between \over and \frac?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73822/5001) for more information on this specific issue.
- There's one group of parentheses that spans (nearly) the entirely formula. To give it a bit more visual prominence, I suggest you (a) use square brackets instead of round parentheses and (b) use `\bigl` and `\bigr` to increase their size a bit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by "beamer" class
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{multline*}
\partial_t \bar{A}_{ij}= e^{-4\phi}
\bigl[-(D_iD_j\alpha)^{TF}
+\alpha(R_{ij}^{TF}-8\pi S_{ij}^{TF})
+\alpha(K\bar{A}_{ij}-2\bar{A}_{il}\bar{A}_j^l)\\
+\beta^k\partial_k\bar{A}_{ij} 
+\bar{A}_{ik}\partial_j \beta^k
+\bar{A}_{kj}\partial_i \beta^k
-\tfrac{2}{3}\bar{A}_{ij}\partial_k \beta^k\bigr]
\end{multline*}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With `\usepackage{amsmath}`:

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{align}
\partial_t \bar{A_{ij}} &= e^{-4\phi}(-(D_iD_j\alpha)^{TF}+\alpha(R_{ij}^{TF}-8\pi S_{ij}^{TF})+\alpha(K\bar{A_{ij}}-2\bar{A_{il}}\bar{A_j^l})
+\beta^k\partial_k\bar{A_{ij}} + \\
& \bar{A_{ik}}\partial_j \beta^k+\bar{A_{kj}}\partial_i \beta^k-{2 \over 3}\bar{A_{ij}}\partial_k \beta^k)
\end{align}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please remove the `$$` instance ahead of `\end{align}`, and please replace the PlainTeX `{2\over3}` construct with LaTeX language, i.e., with `\frac{2}{3}`.

Comment: Thanks for the `$$` but the `{2\over3}` I leave to the user ...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using the `multline` environment, and playing with the `framed` parameters to define an `eqframed` environment, so the distance from the horizontal lines of the frame to the equation body be not too large. Note the frame will be  `\textwidth` wide.

So I propose an alternative solution, based on `empheq` (which loads `amsmath`, so needless to load the latter), which puts an `\fbox` around the equation, and is easier to customise than `framed`. The difference is not very important in the present case since your equation lines are wide:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq, framed}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\newcommand*\widefbox[1]{\setlength{\fboxsep}{8pt}\setlength\fboxrule{1pt}\fcolorbox{IndianRed}{white}{\enspace#1\enspace}}
\newenvironment{eqframed}{\setlength\FrameSep{0pt}\framed}{\endframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqframed}
  \begin{multline*}
    ∂_t \bar{A_{ij}}= e^{-4ϕ}(-(D_iD_jα)^{TF}+α(R_{ij}^{TF}-8πS_{ij}^{TF})+α(K\bar{A_{ij}}-2\bar{A_{il}}\bar{A_j^l})\\
    +\beta^k∂_k\bar{A_{ij}} +
    \bar{A_{ik}}∂_j \beta^k+\bar{A_{kj}}∂_i \beta^k-{2 \over 3}\bar{A_{ij}}∂_k \beta^k)
  \end{multline*}
\end{eqframed}

\begin{empheq}[box=\widefbox]{multline*}
  ∂_t \bar{A_{ij}}= e^{-4ϕ}(-(D_iD_jα)^{TF}+α(R_{ij}^{TF}-8πS_{ij}^{TF})+α(K\bar{A_{ij}}-2\bar{A_{il}}\bar{A_j^l})\\
  +\beta^k∂_k\bar{A_{ij}} +
  \bar{A_{ik}}∂_j \beta^k+\bar{A_{kj}}∂_i \beta^k-{2 \over 3}\bar{A_{ij}}∂_k \beta^k)
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Interesting that you interpreted the OP's code as meaning that he/she wants to place a frame around the displayed equation. I had interpreted the `\begin{frame}` and `\end{frame}` directives as suggesting that the code was taken from a `beamer` document... Let's see if the OP weighs in with more information.

Comment: @Mico: It's the problem with O.P.s posting only code snippets without (at least) explaining the context. I must say I didn't even think of beamer (I rarely use it). Everyone sees it their own way…

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you want a boxed equation with multiple lines then you need to use `\boxed` command with `aligned` environment inside an `equation` environment. Also, the equation above looks crowded, so enhance readability by adding spaces using `\thinspace` command in certain places (such as between `\alpha` and `(`). The source code for the above result:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\boxed{
        \begin{aligned}
            %
            \partial_t \bar{A_{ij}} = & e^{-4\phi} \Big[ -(D_i D_j \alpha)^{TF} + \alpha \thinspace (R_{ij}^{TF} - 8 \pi S_{ij}^{TF}) + \alpha \thinspace (K \bar{A_{ij}} - 2 \bar{A_{il}} \bar{A_j^l})
            \\
            + & \beta^k \partial_k \bar{A_{ij}} + \bar{A_{ik}} \partial_j \beta^k + \bar{A_{kj}} \partial_i \beta^k - {2 \over 3} \bar{A_{ij}} \partial_k  \beta^k) \Big]
            %
        \end{aligned}
    }
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please change `= &` to `&=`. (The asymmetrical whitespace spacing around the first `=` symbol should be a give-away that something isn't quite right.)

Comment: Why did you change `& +` to `+ &`, while leaving `= &` unchanged? Before, you had *one* instance of bad spacing; now, you have *two* such instances. (At least, I suppose, the spacing is *consistently bad* now...)

Comment: In my field, the second line is aligned either with `=` or with the symbol letter after it

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that that there are 2 problems with your current solution: (i) The whitespace around the `=` symbol in the first row is rather asymmetric; (ii) there's no whitespace at all between `+` symbol and `\beta^k` at the start of the second row. This makes that `+` symbol look like a unary operator instead of as a binary operator. Change `= &` and `+ &` to `&=` and `&+`, respectively, and the spacing will be much improved -- *without affecting the alignment across rows.* If you don't believe me, please consult section 3 of the user guide of the `amsmath` package.