# How to define a command that takes the word before it as one of its parameters?

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I want to define a macro `\foo` that behaves similarly to `\over` and `\atop`, such that the code

```
#1 \foo #2
```

outputs

```
foo #1 #2
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you provide a use case for wanting to use `\over`-like notation in a command? The commands `\over` and `\atop`, which are TeX primitives, are actually quite problematic from a design-theoretical perspective. There is a very good reason for why LaTeX provides `\frac` and discourages the use of  `\over`. See also @Aditya's and @barbarabeeton's follow-up comments on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73825/5001) to the query [What is the difference between \over and \frac?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73822/5001)

Comment: The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/73965/5001) by [@AméricoTavares](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1862/am%c3%a9rico-tavares) provides additional information about the nature of the problems caused by the infix syntax of the TeX primitives `\over`, `\atop`, `\above`, etc.

Comment: The commands `\over`, `\atop`, `\above`, etc are implemented as TeX *primitives*, not as *macros*. As such, it's going to be rather tough to come up with new commands that adopt infix notation. Are you open to using a LuaLaTeX-based solution that acts like a preprocessor?

Comment: @Mico I would like to redefine ```\to``` into a command that generates a ```xymatrix``` and takes the word before ```\to``` as the domain of a function and the word after it as the codomain. Right now I have something like this.
```\renewcommand{\to}[3][]{\xymatrix@1{#2 \ar@{->}[r]^{#1} & #3}}```.

Comment: the infix `\over` (possibly _the worst_ aspect of the tex design), is not implementable using TeX macros. If you have any prefix you could have some syntax such as `\zzz ... \to ...`  where `\zzz` grabs the expression and splits on `\to`, but you can not "go back".

Comment: @FR09 - I'm afraid I'm not familiar with `\xymatrix` and its syntax. Would you mind editing the body of your posting to spell out exactly how you expect the input to be formatted? Thanks.

Comment: @FR09 in `$a+ { b + xyz \over 2}$` the numerator is `b+xyz` but your request for your `\to` to take "the previous word" would suggest that in `$a+ { b + xyz \to 2}$`  you want `#1` to be `xyz` or `z`  not `b+xyz`. without Lua none of these is implementable but which do you have in mind?

Comment: Since this feature seems to take a lot more effort than I imagined, I don't consider it necessary. Thank you for your help!