# Apparent runaway argument that started with an attempted \begin{align*} environment in \documentclass{amsart}

Tags: errors, texshop

[image: error message]Here is my document and the problem:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
 \graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}
\section{The Binomial Distribution}

If $X \sim Bin(n,p)$ where $p = \frac{1}{2}$, hence $q = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$, then 


\begin{align*} 
 P(X=k) &= {n\choose k}p^k q^{n-k}\\
    &= {n\choose k}{\frac{1]{2}}^k \frac{1]{2}^{n-k}\\
    &= {n\choose k}{\frac{1]{2}}^n\\
    &= \frac{n\choose k}{2^n}
\end{align*}


Note that $2^n$ is constant for fixed $n$. Therefore, $P(X=k)$ has symmetry matching the symmetry of Pascal's Triangle.
If $p < \frac{1}{2}$, the distribution is negatively skewed.  


\begin{align*}
P(X=k) &= {n\choose k}p^k q^{n-k}\\
    &= {n\choose k}{\frac{1]{6}}^k \frac{5]{6}^{n-k}\\
    &= \frac{n\choose k 5^{n-k}}{6^n} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

So there seems to be problems from \section{The Binomial Distribution} onwards. Before when I typeset, it kept saying there was a "missing $ inserted" and I played around with it, unfortunately messing it up so much that now it only has "Undefined control sequence \document class{amsart}" as the error message. Please help!

**Follow up question**

Here is my entire code (excluding information which I think isn't contributing to an error):

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
 \graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}



1. $\frac{(n\times p)!}{p!^n}$

\vspace{5mm}

2. Want to borrow $1$ to $n$ books:\\



There are $38$ numbers and only $26$ differences when maximised, so the ceiling function $\lceil \frac{38}{26} \rceil =2$.\\
Therefore by PHP, there exists at least two numbers whose difference is at most $26$

\section{Statistics}
\subsection{Averages from grouped data}
\hfill\\
\textbf{Estimating the mean:} An estimate for the mean can be obtained by assuming hat each of the raw data values takes the midpoint value of the interval in which it has been placed
$$\text{Mean estimate}  =\frac{\sum{fx}}{\sum{f}}$$

\subsection{Pareto Charts}
\hfill\\
The following table shows the 6 most common reasons for conditions failing their driving test.\\
\hfill\\

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
Reason                    & Percentage of conditions & Cumulative frequency \\ \midrule
Observations at junctions & 11.9                     & 31                   \\
Use of mirrors            & 8.2                      & 52.4                 \\
Inappropriate speed       & 5.1                      & 65.7                 \\
Steering control          & 4.7                      & 77.9                 \\
Reversing around corner   & 4.3                      & 89.1                 \\
Incorrect positioning     & 4.2                      & 100                  \\ \bottomrule
Total                          &38.4            \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\hfill \\

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{paretochart1}
\caption{Pareto chart}
\label{default}
\end{figure}

\newpage
\textbf{Note:} 
\begin{itemize}
\item The Cumulative frequency graph is concave down and monotone increasing
\item Pareto Principle: 80\% of consequences come from 20\% of the causes
\item Deciles:
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 0 - 10\% 1st decile
    \item 10 - 20\% 2nd decile
    \item $\vdots$
    \item 90 - 100\% 10th decile
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}


\section{The Binomial Distribution}

If $X \sim Bin(n,p)$ where $p = \frac{1}{2}$, hence $q = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$, then 


\begin{align*} 
 P(X=k) &= {n\choose k}p^k q^{n-k}\\
    &= {n\choose k}{\frac{1}{2}}^k \frac{1}{2}^{n-k}\\
    &= {n\choose k}{\frac{1}{2}}^n\\
    &= \frac{{n\choose k}}{2^n}
\end{align*}


Note that $2^n$ is constant for fixed $n$. Therefore, $P(X=k)$ has symmetry matching the symmetry of Pascal's Triangle.
If $p < \frac{1}{2}$, the distribution is negatively skewed.  


\begin{align*}
P(X=k) &= {n\choose k}p^k q^{n-k}\\
    &= {n\choose k}{\frac{1}{6}}^k \frac{5}{6}^{n-k}\\
    &= \frac{{n\choose k 5^{n-k}}}{6^n} 
\end{align*}


Note that $5^{n-k}$ does affect the symmetry. If $k$ is small, probabilities to left of the mode are higher. If $k$ is large, probabilities to the right of the mode are lower.


\end{document}
```

Comment: One problem is multiple instances of `\frac{1]` with mismatched delimiters

Comment: yikes thats horrifying. Ok I fixed them all. The error message is still  "Undefined control sequence \document class{amsart}". I think I moved something and mismatched delimiters is no longer the main problem

Comment: Are you accidentally compiling with pdftex, instead of pdflatex?

Comment: how can I tell?

Comment: YES indeed the error log says pdftex. How can I change it back to pdflatex? I may have accidentally changed it somehow.

Comment: Sorry - all of my other documents are being compiled in pdftex as well and they work fine. I didn't change anything

Comment: Well, I don't use TeXLive, but my MikTeX identifies as `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.3) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.5.31)`, which is definitely different than `format=pdftex`.

Comment: I am so sorry for the confusion - you are indeed correct. See the error message i included? it does say format=pdftex. How do I fix this?

Comment: I don't use TeXLive to advise.  In the MikTeX editor (Texworks), there is a pull-down menu in the upper left where such things are set, right next to compile button.

Comment: Thank you, my problem is solved. I changed it back. Why does format= pdftex NOT typeset properly?

Comment: dont use \choose in latex use \binom{n}{m}

Comment: Off-topic: The claim that "If p < 0.5, the [Binomial] distribution is negatively skewed" is *false*. In fact, the exact opposite is true.

Comment: pdftex does typeset properly if you process a plain tex document. The syntax of plain tex is different, ( `a \choose b` is plain syntax that should not be used in laetx for example) so it's like asking why an English spell checker doesn't work properly on a German text.

Comment: never use `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph, you do get warnings about badness 10000 (ie as bad as possible) from `2. Want to borrow $1$ to $n$ books:\\ `

Comment: @Mico yeah sorry a typo - it should be positively skewed

Comment: "never use \\  at the end of a paragraph, you do get warnings about badness 10000 (ie as bad as possible) from 2. Want to borrow $1$ to $n$ books:\\" @DavidCarlisle can you please expand on its point? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Ok I didnt know that. Well then why is it just so that \choose works in latex AND tex? Is it actually "bad" , or just a nit picky thing? (to use \binom over \choose)

Comment: @user never ignore warnings, see the warning you get from this example (I copied it under Steven's answer)

Comment: My earlier comment was about the three warnings that you get from the above `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 33--36`  badness is tex's internal check on the quality of the output and 10000 is the maximum value so tex is telling you it is giving up and the output will be bad. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334249/1090

Comment: tex is a macro expansion language so higher level languages like latex can not hide lower level constructs there is no compilation step or internal function definitions as with compiled languages, so every lower level contruct is accessible, it just shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer addresses the OP's follow-up question, not the question that was posted initially.)

Some general observations about your code:

- In LaTeX documents, one should not use `{n \choose k}` or `{1 \over 2}` infix-style notation. Period. Instead, use `\binom{n}{k}` and `\frac{1}{2}`, respectively. For more on this subject, see [What is the difference between `\over` and `\frac`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73822/5001)
- In LaTeX documents, don't use `$$` to initiate and terminate display-math mode. Instead, use `\[` and `\]`. For a detailed discussion, please see [Why is `\[ ... \]` preferable to `$$ ... $$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/5001)
- There's an overabundance of visual formatting directives in your code. For the most part, they don't cause errors, but they're often redundant and create a lot of code clutter. E.g., most of the `\hfill\\` directives could be replaced with simple blank lines. Likewise, most of the `\\` line terminators in running text can and should be dropped.
- Notation such as `{\frac{1}{2}}^k` is not conducive to good typography. For one, the curly braces around `\frac{1}{2}` are redundant. Second, and more importantly, there's very little visual difference between `\frac{1}{2}^k` and `\frac{1^k}{2}`. Since the latter impression should obviously be avoided at nearly all cost, please start to write (in a display-math context) `\biggl(\frac{1}{2}\biggr)^{\!k}`. Your readers will very much appreciate it.
- Don't create paragraph breaks right before display-math material.
- Do please give your readers a (visual) break by replacing diminutive-looking constructs such as `\frac{{n\choose k}}{2^n}` and `\frac{\binom{n}{k 5^{n-k}}}{6^n}` with much more reader-friendly alternatives such as `\binom{n}{k}2^{-n}` and `\frac{\binom{n}{k 5^{n-k}}}{6^n}`. Try it!

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question, about why I called `\frac{{n\choose k}}{2^n}` "diminutive looking" and why I suggested using `\binom{n}{k}2^{-n}` instead. After all, aren't they the same *mathematically*? Of course they are the same mathematically; however, they're they're not at all the same *typographically*. TeX and LaTeX are typographic tools, so use them well to maximize the readability of what you're writing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \binom macro
\begin{document}
\[
\frac{{n\choose k}}{2^n} \quad\text{vs.}\quad  \binom{n}{k}2^{-n}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This information is very valuable to me. I'm the only person in my class who uses LaTeX so I don't get any support except from the few "tutorial LaTeX" booklets that I read

Comment: One question: what does " diminutive-looking constructs" mean? They are the same mathematical expression

Comment: @user71207 - Please see the addendum I posted to further explain why I called one of the terms in your code "diminutive looking". Just because two typographic expressions have the same mathematical meaning doesn't mean that their readability and legibility is the same as well.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Not going to lie, but I find both equally readable. What makes the second more preferable? Actually I think I prefer this over both: $$\frac{1}{2^n}\binom{n}{k}$$

Answer (score 4):

There were two issues: One problem is multiple instances of `\frac{1]` with mismatched delimiters, and syntax like `\frac{n\choose k}{2^n}`.  Apparently it needs an extra set of braces to unconfuse it.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
% \graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}
\section{The Binomial Distribution}

If $X \sim Bin(n,p)$ where $p = \frac{1}{2}$, hence $q = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$, then 


\begin{align*} 
 P(X=k) &= {n\choose k}p^k q^{n-k}\\
    &= {n\choose k}{\frac{1}{2}}^k \frac{1}{2}^{n-k}\\
    &= {n\choose k}{\frac{1}{2}}^n\\
    &= \frac{{n\choose k}}{2^n}
\end{align*}


Note that $2^n$ is constant for fixed $n$. Therefore, $P(X=k)$ has symmetry matching the symmetry of Pascal's Triangle.
If $p < \frac{1}{2}$, the distribution is negatively skewed.  


\begin{align*}
P(X=k) &= {n\choose k}p^k q^{n-k}\\
    &= {n\choose k}{\frac{1}{6}}^k \frac{5}{6}^{n-k}\\
    &= \frac{{n\choose k 5^{n-k}}}{6^n} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but the error message is still "Undefined control sequence \document class{amsart}". I think I moved something and mismatched delimiters is no longer the main problem

Comment: Ill add a photo in my post

Comment: I confirm it works on a fresh document. Therefore there is something else in my document that is wrong. What should  I do know? Do I include my entire code?

Comment: If I misunderstood the question, then clarifying the question can be helpful on your part.  However, if you misunderstood the problem and I properly answered the misunderstood question, then it is generally poor form to revise the question in such a way that makes existing answers obsolete.  Best to ask a new question in such a case.

Comment: I will update my question, marking a clear follow up question

Comment: Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atopwithdelims;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 21.
  ie use `\binom{a}{b}` not `{{a \choose b}}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `format=pdftex` then don't use LaTeX's constructions in your document, i.e. don't use any macros like `\documentclass`, `\usepackage`, `\begin{document}` etc. Use simply plain TeX. It is much more simple than usage of LaTeX.

Comment: I didnn't even know TeX was a thing. Should I be using that instead of LaTeX? Where can I find a tutorial for TeX? I'm just interested in seeing how that commands may differ from LaTx

Comment: A short summary about TeX is in http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/tex-nutshell/tex-nutshell.pdf for example.