# Decrease whitespace in align environment

Tags: align

I have the following in an align environment

```
\begin{align*}
{2 + 2 - 1}\choose{2 - 1} &=& {2 + 2 - 1}\choose{2} \\
{3}\choose{1} &=& {3}\choose{2} \\
3 &=& 3
\end{align*}
```

but there is a lot of whitespace on the righthand side of the = sign.

Is there a workaround that eliminates the whitespace?

Comment: the syntax for align is `&=` not `&=&` also use `\binom{a}{b}` not  `a \choose b`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle When I use &=, the = sign is included within the binomial coefficient instead of outside it. Also, why \binom{a}{b} over a \choose b?

Comment: \choose is not latex syntax (and requires some care to be used in latex without breaking things as you just commented) , you are using the amsmath package which defines `\binom` specifically for this use. If you do use `\choose` (don't) the syntax for that plain tex command is `{2+2+1 \choose 2}` not `{2+2+1}\choose {2}`  if used that way it will not grab the = but `\binom` is the correct form

Comment: It's like \frac vs. \over.  It wasn't just an homage to Battlestar Gallactica.

Comment: @compbiostats -- For more on the `\frac` vs. `\over` issue (and hence, indirectly, the `\binom` vs. `\choose` issue), see the posting [What is the difference between \over and \frac?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73822/5001) (Shameless self-citation alert!)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

AMS alignments are all written to use a syntax with the alignment point just to the left of the relation (unlike the deprecated `eqnarray`) so `&=` not `&=&`. The LaTeX syntax for a binomial coefficient is `\binom{a}{b}`  note that `\choose` is a plain tex macro that should not be used in LaTeX if you do use it `amsmath` warns

```
Package amsmath Warning: Foreign command \atopwithdelims;
(amsmath)                \frac or \genfrac should be used instead
(amsmath)                 on input line 11.
```

Also if you use it the syntax is `{2+2-1 \choose 2}` not `{2+2-1}\choose{2}` otherwise it will pick up everything before the `\choose` such as the `=` in your example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\binom{2 + 2 - 1}{2 - 1} &= \binom{2 + 2 - 1}{2} \\
\binom{3}{1} &= \binom{3}{2}  \\
3 &= 3
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```