# Why is grouping used in the numerator of the definition of \frac but not the denominator?

Tags: tex-core, fractions, latex-base

In the answers to this question: [What is the difference between \over and \frac?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73822/965), one finds the ams and plain latex definitions of `\frac`, respectively:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\frac}[2]{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\@@over#2}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\frac[2]{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\over#2}}
```

Is there a reason grouping is not used around `#2`? That is, like this:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\frac}[2]{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\@@over\begingroup#2\endgroup}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\frac[2]{{\begingroup#1\endgroup\over\begingroup#2\endgroup}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

declarations in the numerator of a primitive `{ ... \over ...}` can leak in to the denominator, but an extra group in the denominator would do nothing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\[
{ a \over b}
+
{ \fam0 a \over b}
+
{\begingroup \fam0 a \endgroup \over b}
\]

\end{document}
```