# Any difference between \binom vs \choose?

Tags: math-mode

Any reason to prefer one over the other? Or are they exactly the same?

Comment: The result should be exactly the same, but `\binom` is defined in LaTeX terms, with two arguments, explicitly delimited in braces.  `\choose`, on the other hand, is plain TeX and requires more care in its input, since its beginning and end are not clear. The result may not be what's expected.  (I'm not sure; `\choose` may by now have been "disabled" in LaTeX.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton It's not disabled. With `amsmath` you get a warning about “Foreign command `\atopwithdelims`” (which is a bit unclear…), essentially because `\choose` is `\atopwithdelims()`

Comment: For a related discussion, see [What is the difference between \over and \frac?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73822/5001)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- `\choose` is a plain-TeX math-mode macro. Syntax: `{n-k\choose k}`. Note that the macro uses TeX's (in)famous infix syntax.
- `\binom` is a LaTeX math-mode macro provided by the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package. Syntax: `\binom{n-k}{k}`. No infix syntax here; instead, two explicit arguments.
- A comparable distinction arises between plain-TeX's `\over` directive, to be used as `{a+b\over c+d}`, versus LaTeX's `\frac` macro, to be used as `\frac{a+b}{c+d}`. If you're not used to TeX's infix notation syntax, you're probably better off sticking with the LaTeX macros.
- Just like the `amsmath` package provides `\dfrac` and `\tfrac` as display-style and text-style companions to `\frac`, the package also provides the macros `\dbinom` and `\tbinom` as companions to `\binom`. There is no equivalent one-letter modifier for `\choose` or, for that matter, `\over`.
- When used appropriately, both `\choose` and `\binom` should give exactly the same result. Emphasis on *appropriately*. As always, if you know what you're doing, there's no real downside to using `\choose` along with its infix syntax. In contrast, if you're not in that group, using `\binom` (or `\tbinom` or `\dbinom`) is probably the way to go.

Comment: +1, of course. The net is plagued with expressions such as “`x-1/x+1`”, which stem from the practice of saying “x minus one over x plus one”, which may be clarified *in speech* by appropriate pauses: “x minus one (pause) over (pause) x plus one”, compared to “x plus (pause) one over x (pause) plus 1”. The TeX primitive syntax has no counterpart for those pauses and this is its main fault.

Comment: @egreg -- Braces are the counterpart of the pauses, but of course braces are only visible, not audible.  (And, of course, under some circumstances, can be omitted.)